# Which query to use for better performance, join in SQL or using Dataset API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

While fetching and manipulating data from HBASE using spark, `*Spark sql join*` vs `*spark dataframe join*` - which one is faster?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the corresponding query plans using `explain`? That would help answering your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell， they should behave the same regarding to performance. SQL internally will work as DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

RDD always Outperform Dataframe and SparkSQL, but from my experience Dataframe perform well compared to SparkSQL. Dataframe function perform well compare to spark sql.Below link will give some insights on this.

[Spark RDDs vs DataFrames vs SparkSQL](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html)

Comment: the link you posted regards Spark 1.6. Now, in Spark 2.0 SparkSQL leverages whole stage code generation which speed up up to 10X the queries. Thus, the data you provided and what you stated is outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a cluster to properly test but I imagine that the Spark SQL just compiles down to the native data frame code.

The rule of thumb I've heard is that the SQL code should be used for exploration and dataframe operations for production code.

Comment: I am not convinced by this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL brings a powerful new optimization framework called Catalyst. Using Catalyst, Spark can automatically transform SQL queries so that they execute more efficiently.

A DataFrame is a Dataset organized into named columns. It is conceptually equivalent to a table in a relational database or a data frame in R/Python, but with richer optimizations, that provides the benefits of RDDs (strong typing, ability to use powerful lambda functions) with the benefits of Spark SQL’s optimized execution engine.

The execution speed will be the same, because they use same optimization algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If the join might be shared across queries carefully implemented join with RDDs might be a good option. However if this is not the case let spark/catalyst do it's job and join within spark sql. It will do all the optimization. So you wouldn't have to maintain your join logic etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL join and Spark Dataframe join are almost same thing. The join is actually delegated to RDD operations under the hood. On top of RDD operation we have convenience methods like spark sql, data frame or data set. In case of spark sql it needs to spend a tiny amount of extra time to parse the SQL.

It should be evaluated more in terms of good programming practice. I like dataset because you can catch syntax errors while compiling. And the encodes behind the scene takes care of compacting the data and executing the query.

Answer (score -1):

I did some performance analysis for sql vs dataframe on Cassandra using spark, I think it will be the same for HBASE also.

According to me sql works faster than dataframe approach. The reason behind this might be that in the dataframe approach there are lot of java object's involved. In sql approach everything is done in-memory.

Attaching results.

[image]

Comment: dataframe is not rdd !

Comment: @54l3d They all build on top of each other. In the end, no matter the method, your execution plan is extracted as a DAG from a RDD. SQL is a more abstract definition of what you want to do with multiple possible execution plans. How good a plan is chosen is the secret sauce of your SQL engine. Who is better in generating an appropriate RDD, human or machine?